# VMWare Workstation VMs Change IP Address without powering on

Tags: networking, router, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

my home router changed and now new gateway is 192.168.1.254 and i see no way to change it to 192.168.1.1

I changed my physical machines to use 192.168.1.254 as the new gateway now

I have around 200+ VMs all using 192.168.1.1

1. Is there a way to change the Gateway information without powering them on individually?

I looked in the .vmx file i see nothing.

Comment: What network mode are the machines set to? If that's `bridged` then the network settings (such as gateway) are *inside* the VMs, and in order to change them you need to boot the OS up (same as if you had 200 physical machines connected to a router that changed address). On the other hand, it would be highly unusual for a router to *not* allow changing its LAN-side IP.

Comment: network mode is bridged but all these VMs have static IP not dynamic

Comment: Static vs. dynamic IPs doesn't matter, the OS must still know (and remembers) the gateway IP - which in your case needs to be updated. I still think you are looking at the wrong end of the problem. Maybe if you posted the make and model of the router someone would point out how to change its LAN-side IP.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1103348/pace-plc-5268ac-how-to-change-router-gateway-address here's my other question

Comment: You could make a new virtual machine, assign it the 192.168.1.1 address, and make that VM perform gateway duty. (Also, I feel compelled to say that not using DHCP for 200+ VMs seems rather unwise.)

Comment: @jamesdlin Most of these are windows or linux Server OS with application servers installed and many of them don't like dynamic IPs and then i have some products of which various version, So they all have unique MACs but same IPs that way when i have to test something in different version i can do that without breaking all my integrations

Comment: @SeanClt: Good DHCP servers can be configured to assign specific IP addresses to machines with specific MAC addresses ("static DHCP").  For machines with different software versions, you could give them identical MAC addresses (since you wouldn't want those machines to be powered on at the same time anyway).

Answer (score 0):

All my VMs have a batch file that starts at login which calls some other batch files and a vbscript. mixture of these batch files does event viewer cleanup and other directory cleanup etc

So inside my vbscript i added following code, which basically cleans up existing DNS Server and adds two of them one of which is my local DNS Server

***Startup Script to Fix DNS***

```
'Fix DNS Servers
ComputerName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").ComputerName
Select Case ComputerName
Case "LAB1","LAB2","LAB3"
    '
Case Else
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsserver ""Local Area Connection"" all"
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver ""Local Area Connection"" address=192.168.1.201"
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "netsh interface ipv4 add dnsserver ""Local Area Connection"" address=192.168.1.1"
End Select
```

---

Now it's just a matter of waiting 5 minutes for my script to finish and these machines are connected to my network again