# Pace Plc 5268AC how to change Router/Gateway Address

Tags: router, gateway

I have AT&T U verse with Router as

Manufacturer    Pace Plc
Model   5268AC

Default router address is 192.168.1.254

I would like to change it to 192.168.1.1

Regards

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: Based on my research, your device, does not allow you (the end user) configure the intranet address it is assigned.

Comment: ARRIS product firmware is always handled by your ISP.  If there isn't an option to change it when you navigate to 192.168.1.254 then it cannot be changed.  AT&T nor ARRIS provide a manual, and the manual for Surfboard makes no mention of that capability.  (Relative because its all the same firmware basically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have is the same [Pace 5268AC described here](http://www.dslreports.com/hardware/Pace-5268AC-h4060) then page 20 of the [linked manual](http://www.dslreports.com/r0/download/2267100~5694a5d84811c1255c4f12556de77ead/5268AC%20Manual.pdf) indicates that you can customize the LAN settings on the Settings / LAN / DHCP page:

> 5. If you selected Configure manually, enter the following information:
>
>    - Router Address. The LAN IP address of the gateway.
>    - Subnet Mask. The subnet mask of the gateway (default: 255.255.255.0).
>    - First DHCP Address. The first IP address in the DHCP IP address pool to be 
>        assigned on the local network.
>    - Last DHCP Address. The last IP address in the DHCP IP address pool to be 
>        assigned on the local network.

In your case, change the `Router Address` from `192.168.1.254` to `192.168.1.1`.

Comment: currently it's using router as DNS, do you know where i can set it to assign the att DNS as DNS on DHCP machines. I looked all pages and still unable to find the setting

Comment: @SeanClt The router (which is itself a DHCP client on the WAN/broadband side) obtains the DNS from AT&T. On the LAN side, the router likely distributes its own local IP for client DNS, which is fairly common. I don't see an option in the config pages for this model to control/override that.